# Allow for importing data from Mendeley and EndNote Web into Careers

Tags: feature-request, jobs

In careers 2.0 there is a part where it is possible to link the books, blogs and articles you have written (or read). Now wouldn't it be possible to import for example all the papers one has written (or read) from mendeley or endnoteweb and list them there, instead of doing it one at a time? Just like it is possible to import all the github repositories at once, but then with the things you've written or read.